# Multiple foreign keys from same entity? (JPA Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have two entities, a Customer and a CustomerTransaction. I want to be able to store two Customer ids within CustomerTransaction as foreign keys (one for the Customer initiating the transaction and one for the Customer receiving). I also want each Customer object to contain a list of all CustomerTransactions they are linked to.

Customer.java

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  //@ManyToOne ?
  private List<CustomerTransaction> customerTransaction;

  //getters and setters
}
```

CustomerTransaction.java

```
@Entity
public class CustomerTransaction {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  //@OneToMany ?
  private Customer initiater;
  //@OneToMany ?
  private Customer receiver;

  private String transactionDetails;

  //getters and setters
}
```

How do I set up the jpa annotations so that each transaction contains a foreign key ID of the customer initiating and receiving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initiater` and `receiver` need to be annotated with `ManyToOne` (many transactions are initiated by the one initiater).

And you need two `OneToMany` in `Customer`: one for the initiated tranactions (`OneToMany(mappedBy = "initiater")`), and one for the received transactions: (`OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")`.

You can't have just one list (and it's probably not desirable anyway).